# Bind to AnyLocalAddress (0.0.0.0) in Java on IPv6-only network

Tags: java, ipv6

In Java, if I write

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress("0.0.0.0",162));
```

Does the wildcard work for IPv6-only networks also?

P.S: I don't have an IPv6-*only* network to test this.

Comment: Use `null` instead. That will work anywhere.Or leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

`"0.0.0.0"` basically means all IP addresses. To ensure that you bind to all known addresses why not do this.

```
DatagramChannel channel = DatagramChannel.open();
channel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(162));
```

Where not specifying the IP address causes it to bind to all ip addresses available on that host.

See - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetSocketAddress.html

> InetSocketAddress(int port)
>
> Creates a socket address where the IP
>   address is the wildcard address and the port number a specified value.
>
> The wildcard is a special local IP address. It usually means "any" and
>   can only be used for bind operations.

Comment: @JavaTechnical Yes.